# MediaWiki call to api.php causes URL Encoding Abuse Attack Attempt

Tags: php, regex, apache, mediawiki, mod-security

I am having unusual (for me) problem with **MediaWiki & ModSecurity** on Shared hosting.
Apparently saving changes or browsing pages causes raise of alarm in ModSecurity module of Apache. After several such alarms user is cut off from server by Firewall module.

Due to the fact that **server isn't under my control** I would like to understand the **root cause** (for instance REGEX rule) and maybe patch MediaWiki.

By combining my raw access log entries and provided error log I've found out that almost all cases are cause by refering to api.php such as:

```
CLIENT IP - - [21/Jun/2014:15:08:18 -0400] "POST /api.php HTTP/1.1" 301 20 "http://adres here/index.php?title=La_vida_cotidiana&action=edit&redlink=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"
```

results in:

```
[Sat Jun 21 15:08:18 2014] [error] [client IP here] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Pattern match "\\\\%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})" at ARGS:text. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "25"] [id "1234123440"] [msg "URL Encoding Abuse Attack Attempt"] [severity "WARNING"] [hostname "hostname here"] [uri "/api.php"] [unique_id "U6XYIsg-ZiYAAD3gn9YAAAAO"]
```

It turned out that there are also other cases (minority):

```
CLIENT IP - - [21/Jun/2014:14:47:51 -0400] "GET /wiki/P%C3%A1gina_principal HTTP/1.1" 200 9378 "http://address here/index.php?title=La_vida_cotidiana&action=edit&redlink=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"

[Sat Jun 21 14:47:51 2014] [error] [client IP] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Pattern match "\\\\%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2}|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})" at ARGS:wpTextbox1. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "25"] [id "1234123440"] [msg "URL Encoding Abuse Attack Attempt"] [severity "WARNING"] [hostname ""] [uri "/index.php"] [unique_id "U6XS8sg-ZiYAAGE2n70AAAAl"]
```

I use:

1. MediaWiki 1.21 (+ FlaggedRevs, Translate, Babel & jQuery text editor)
2. PHP 5.4,
3. Apache 2.2 with url rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

The position of us MediaWiki developers has always been that mod_security is just not compatible with MW. Even if you solve your current problem, next mod_security will freak out at usernames containing single quotes, for example - because "SQL injection attack detected"; and so on. mod_security is simply not suitable for sites with user-posted content.